# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ebooklib'

Tags: python

Hi I'm using ebooklib in python and I'm getting this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ebooklib'
```

I have successfully installed this library and it appears in my pip3 packages list.

I'm importing this in my python file like this

```
import os
import logging
import sys
import json
import traceback
from ast import literal_eval
from htmlparse import MyHTMLParser
from ebooklib import epub
```

I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Could be that you run it using a different Python version / installation or venv?

Comment: Should work, I tried the same thing just now.

Comment: If you're using an IDE, sometimes after installing it wont reload the libraries. Sometimes happens to me using VSCode. Quit the IDE, wait a few seconds, and reopen. Works for me.

Comment: i'm using it on aws on local ide it works fine

Comment: @Invincibleme how exactly do you deploy / run in on aws?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue & fixed it by adding:

```
> export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
```

to my `.bash_profile` file.

To see where your `ebooklib` is installed to

```
print(ebooklib.__file__)
```